# I need to drop a column from a table in matillion-snowflake

Tags: etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I need to drop the column named Conditions before loading it into[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnZP1.png) the target table using matillion ETL for snowflake. however I want to do this in a transformation job.

I've attached the image for reference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you help me solving this

Comment: @AniruddhaShinde any ideas please share

Comment: When you create the step that inserts the data into the target table, just don't reference the Conditions field.  You're not really dropping a column from a table in Snowflake, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jon_snow_0702 try update table instead of rewrite table